# Insert into table of multi tenancy project

Tags: sql

I need to update(or insert, I dont do a lot of sql work so I dont know which one I really need) some data in our database but its a multi tenant db and I am having trouble specifying which tenant I want to insert into. The current value in the column for this table is *NULL*. I need to add some data into that column

I need to do something like:

`INSERT INTO Tenant(Address1) Values('5800 Nova Dr') WHERE TenantId='2'`

[image]

Its the "WHERE" part that Azure Data Studio is not liking. Everything I found online was about inserting from another table. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is throwing an error at the WHERE.

Comment: *where* belongs in a *select* statement, it has no meaning with insert values; you probably need to include the *TenantId* as a column in the insert list; however you both mention *insert* and *update* so your intentions really are not clear.

Comment: It appears that you really want to update  the address of the existing Tenant with TenantId='2'; you should use the `UPDATE` statement. INSERT is used if there is no record.

Comment: @userMT there is current a column it is just NULL. What would the syntax be using UPDATE?

Comment: @Stu the column exists but its null, so the goal is to add the values into address one, where the tenantId is 2... not sure if that is an update or insert particularly. Some guidance there would be helpful

Comment: Well do you need to insert a new row of data or change an existing row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use insert syntax to add a new row if you know the tenantId number

`INSERT INTO Tenant(TenantId, Address1) Values(2, '5800 Nova Dr');`

use update syntax if you have already prefilled the table row with null values

```
UPDATE Tenant SET Address1='5800 Nova Dr' WHERE TenantId=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work if your table have an autoincrement value as primary key, otherwise you need to specify also the TenantID.
You can't use `WHERE` in insert, because is a new row.

`INSERT INTO Tenant(Address1) values ('5800 Nova Dr')`

If you want to update the value of already existing raw you can use

`UPDATE Tenant SET Address1 = "5800 Nova Dr" WHERE Address1 like = '5800 Nova Dr'`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Tenant SET Address1='5800 Nova Dr' WHERE TenantId='2'